# Architecture MNIST, fully connected layer 1, output size

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I don't understand part of this ([quora: How does the last layer of a ConvNet connects to the first fully  connected layer](https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-last-layer-of-a-ConvNet-connects-to-the-first-fully-connected-layer)):

> Make an one hot representation of feature maps. So we would have 64 *
>   7 * 7 = 3136 input features which is again processed by a 3136 neurons
>   reducing it to 1024 features. The matrix multiplication this layer
>   would be (1x3136) * (3136x1024) => 1x1024

I mean, what is the process to reduce 3136 inputs using 3136 neurons to 1024 features?

Comment: Quotation properly marked. The link reformatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would explain it using layman's terms how I understand it.

One hot representation of feature maps is a way for categorical values to be represented by a matrix using 1 and 0. This is a way for machines to read/process the data (in your example, an image or a picture). Then ig makes computations using matrix algebra.

Now the part of the computation is multiplication of 1 row and 3136 columns of binary values (1 or 0) and another matrix of size 3136 rows and 1024 columns. When you multiple these two matrices, the resulting matrix is 1 row and 1024 columns. This is now the matrix of 1's and 0's  that represents your image or picture.

Comment: yes, I understand the multiplication of matrices, but not exactly where the 1024 comes from

Comment: it is an arbitrary dimension used in converting the image into a vector (matrix) form. You can also use 128 but it is not accurate or 2048-D which is very accurate but needs more computing power.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I got your question right.

You need to understand matrix multiplication. (1x3136) * (3136x1024) is an example of matrix multiplication that first multiplier's((1x3136)) column number must be equal to second multiplier's (3136x1024) row number. This results in (1x1024) because first multiplier's row becomes result's row, while second multiplier's column becomes result's column.

Also, check this :

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/precalc-matrices/multiplying-matrices-by-matrices/v/multiplying-a-matrix-by-a-matrix